# receiving GPG error while using sudo apt update in Pop!_OS 22.04

Tags: upgrade, key-authentication, pop-os

I ran this command in Terminal:

```
sudo apt update
```

At the end I received this message:

````
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
W: Failed to fetch https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/edge/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY EB3E94ADBE1229CF
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.``` 

Currently running Pop!_OS 22.04 which is based on Ubuntu 22.04
````

Answer (score 0):

You should install public key from here:
https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc

and then try to install/update packages from Microsoft.
You can check [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/linux-package-repository-for-microsoft-software) how to add this key to your distribution.

Comment: Do you know what to type in curl command, it changes from version to version. I'm using Pop!_OS 22.04 which is based on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: This is another question, please use this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 0):

apt-key now seems to be deprecated, I have created a script that will detect and get the missing keys, you can get it [here](https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2320252).

```
#!/bin/sh -e
tmp="$(mktemp)"
sudo apt-get update 2>&1 | sed -En 's/.*NO_PUBKEY ([[:xdigit:]]+).*/\1/p' | sort -u > "${tmp}"
cat "${tmp}" | xargs sudo gpg --keyserver "hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443" --recv-keys  # to /usr/share/keyrings/*
cat "${tmp}" | xargs -L 1 sh -c 'sudo gpg --yes --output "/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/$1.gpg" --export "$1"' sh  # to /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/*
rm "${tmp}"
```

Comment: As with the other questions that you have answered with identical answers, this question is not about Ubuntu, so you would have to tailor the answer to the specific OS that is used.

Comment: the key servers should actually be interchangeable and this is the one i found to be the most complete.